# Python with bs4 reading an rss feed, bot posting to discord, I need quotes to appear with ">" in front of them

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a bot that scrapes data from a forum and posts in a discord channel. I'm using urllib to read the RSS feed, and bs4 to parse it. Let's say I get this from the RSS feed:

```
<item>
        <title>What Music Do You Build Robots to?</title>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[@TaranMayer TaranMayer ]]></dc:creator>
        <description><![CDATA[ <aside class="quote no-group" data-username="Kajunii42" data-post="37" data-topic="84065" data-full="true">
<div class="title">
<div class="quote-controls"></div>
<img alt="" width="20" height="20" src="https://www.vexforum.com/letter_avatar_proxy/v4/letter/k/e274bd/40.png" class="avatar"> Kajunii42:</div>
<blockquote>
<p>HECK YES DUDE F-777 IS KING!!! whats ur favorite song?</p>
</blockquote>
</aside>
<p>F-777 are the ones that are used in Geometry Dash all the time, right?</p> ]]></description>
        <link>https://www.vexforum.com/t/what-music-do-you-build-robots-to/84065/38</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 02 Sep 2020 21:56:44 +0000</pubDate>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">www.vexforum.com-post-669155</guid>
</item>
```

On our forum, a user can quote a previous post, or multiple previous posts, and that shows up in `<blockquote>` tags in the RSS feed. They don't have to quote someone, so it won't always be there, and what I'm asking won't always be necessary.

Seeing as it will be posting on discord, I need the quote part to start with `>`to get it to appear in quote blocks. This is an example of what I need to get before the bot can send it on Discord:

```
> Kajunii42:
>
> HECK YES DUDE F-777 IS KING!!! whats ur favorite song?

F-777 are the ones that are used in Geometry Dash all the time, right?
```

How do I insert a `>` character in front of every line that appears in the `<blockquote>` tags?

Comment: How are you extracting text from the `<blockquote>` element? How have you tried solving this problem so far?

Comment: So far I've just been extracting the text from the `<description>` tag and by some miracle, it formats in a way that's technically readable but not great.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this will meet your requirements.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req
html = '''
<item>
        <title>What Music Do You Build Robots to?</title>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[@TaranMayer TaranMayer ]]></dc:creator>
        <description><![CDATA[ <aside class="quote no-group" data-username="Kajunii42" data-post="37" data-topic="84065" data-full="true">
<div class="title">
<div class="quote-controls"></div>
<img alt="" width="20" height="20" src="https://www.vexforum.com/letter_avatar_proxy/v4/letter/k/e274bd/40.png" class="avatar"> Kajunii42:</div>
<blockquote>
<p>HECK YES DUDE F-777 IS KING!!! whats ur favorite song?</p>
</blockquote>
</aside>
<p>F-777 are the ones that are used in Geometry Dash all the time, right?</p> ]]></description>
        <link>https://www.vexforum.com/t/what-music-do-you-build-robots-to/84065/38</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 02 Sep 2020 21:56:44 +0000</pubDate>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">www.vexforum.com-post-669155</guid>
</item>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
description = doc.getElement('item').getElement('description')
name = description.getElement('div', value='title').text
content = '> ' + name
blockquote = description.blockquote
if blockquote:
    content = content + '\n> ' + blockquote.text
content = content + '\n' + description.getElement('p', start='</aside>').text
print(content)
```

Result:

```
> Kajunii42:
> HECK YES DUDE F-777 IS KING!!! whats ur favorite song?
F-777 are the ones that are used in Geometry Dash all the time, right?
```